# How to debug chrome extension with a popup window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am try to using devtool to debug a chrome extension.
This extension works as a dictionary,in any webpage if you want to check the meaning of one word,move the mouse to the word and click "shift" button,a popup window will show to translate the word you selected.

[popup window is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL22p.png)

I want to know how to debug such popup behavior with devtools,any assistance is highly appreciated.

Extension link:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yomichan/ogmnaimimemjmbakcfefmnahgdfhfami
Extension source code:https://github.com/FooSoft/yomichan

Comment: This is not a window but a DOM element. Right-click it, then choose "Inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm , great answer, thanks for your help!